# Why convertible-text is deprecated?

Tags: haskell

I tried to relax constraints on `time-http` but now I see that it`s dependency is deprecated. What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

I no longer believe that the highly polymorphic nature of convertible is really the right thing to do.

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with the package, but from just reading your statement: I'm curious of why is that? I mean, why isn't it the right thing to do anymore?

Comment: To clarify: I mean that I no longer feel it's the right thing to do, not that it used to be right but things have changed. Having arbitrary `convert` calls that convert one type to another without any clear constraints in place can lead to confusing code.